# The symbol "-" creates issue when used in page names in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby on rails and working in a new test application. Consider my application url is : `www.test.com`

I would like to place a page by creating controller and respective views, the page should look like the below

`www.test.com/articles/book-test-page`

I created a controller "article" (defined the action as

```
def book_test_page

...

...

end
```

and folder under view as view/articles/book-test-page.

What routing information should i add in the routes.rb file to make this url bring up the specified url work? Any suggestion would be helpful..

Thanks,
Balan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
get 'articles/book-test-page', :to => 'articles#book_test_page'
```